# Ad-hoc shortened URL using Redirect / Rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to print a short, easy-to-type URL on paper brochures.

So that people can type `example.com/foo` into their smartphone browser, and the browser will display an existing page, say `http://example.com/bar/yada.php` .

I see that most pages about modrewrite involve regex, but what if I only need manually defined single pages?

Should I have an actual `foo` directory in the web root, containing a .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

The following did what I needed, placed in the .htaccess at webroot.

An actual `foo` directory need not exist.

```
RedirectMatch 301 "(?i)^/foo$" "/bar/yada.php"
RedirectMatch 301 "(?i)^/foo/$" "/bar/yada.php"
```